# Unpacking real and imaginary parts of complex numbers into separate ymm registers

Tags: complex-numbers, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I need to read a sequence of complex single precision numbers, stored like [real1, imag1, real2, imag2, ...] into ymm registers and unpack them such that, say, ymm0 contains [real1, real2, real3, ...] and ymm1 contains [imag1, imag2, imag3, ...]. The following code works, but uses four lane-crossing shuffles. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this than what I'm doing here?

```
    // the negatives here stand in for imaginary parts
    float _f[] = {1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8};

    int i[] = {0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7};

    __m256 a = _mm256_loadu_ps(_f);
    __m256 b = _mm256_loadu_ps(_f+8);

    __m256i x = _mm256_loadu_si256((void*)i);

    __m256 c = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(a, x);
    __m256 d = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(b, x);

    __m256 e = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(c, d, 0x20);
    __m256 f = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(c, d, 0x31);
```

At the end of this sequence, e contains the real parts and f contains the imaginary parts. My only concern is that lane-crossing shuffles can be expensive on some machines.

Comment: Good point! Now that you mention it, the actual order does not matter, it's just essential that one vector contains all the real parts and the other all the imaginary parts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by harold, this will do the job of separating the real and imaginary parts into seperate vectors, but the order won't be exactly right. Instead, `e` will have [real1, real5, real2, real6, ...] and `f` will have the corresponding imaginary parts. This may be good enough for some applications so I figured it was worth posting in case anybody else finds it useful

```
    float _f[] = {1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8};

    __m256 a = _mm256_loadu_ps(_f);
    __m256 b = _mm256_loadu_ps(_f+8);

    __m256 c = _mm256_permute_ps(a, 0xd8);
    __m256 d = _mm256_permute_ps(b, 0xd8);

    __m256 e = _mm256_unpacklo_ps(c,d);
    __m256 f = _mm256_unpackhi_ps(c,d);
```

EDIT: And, as pointed out by Peter Cordes, the following even shorter solution produces [real1, real2, real5, real6, real3, real4, real7, real8] and the corresponding imaginaries.

```
    float _f[] = {1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8};

    __m256 a = _mm256_loadu_ps(_f);
    __m256 b = _mm256_loadu_ps(_f+8);

    __m256 c = _mm256_shuffle_ps(a, b, 0x88);
    __m256 d = _mm256_shuffle_ps(a, b, 0xdd);
```

Comment: You should be able to use `vshufps` to grab the real parts of 2 vectors, so one shuffle each to grab all the real parts, and another to grab the imaginary parts.

Comment: Yup, that's what I had in mind.  BTW, there's a `_MM_SHUFFLE` macro for writing those 4x 2-bit shuffle constants in a meaningful way, like `_MM_SHUFFLE(2,0, 2,0)`

Comment: If your surrounding code is bottlenecked on shuffle throughput (e.g. Intel before Ice Lake, if you're shuffling the results back into order), you can trade one of the shuffles for 2 blends: `vpermilps(a, swap_dwords)` and then blend both ways with the other input (1 uop for any SIMD execution port for `vblendps y,y,i`) .  Or use `vshufps a,a, imm` for the swap because Ice Lake runs it at 2/clock, vs. `vpermilps ymm,ymm, imm` at 1/clock even on Ice Lake.  The memory source version of vpermilps can't micro-fuse on Intel so it still costs the same as load+vshufps.  Less on AMD. https://uops.info/